# Starting another activity in onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app, I have an entry activity (dummy, without layout) which checks the accounts in the account manager:

- If there exist an account of certain type: start the main activity
- Else, **start an activity for getting the user credentials** (to add it to accounts)

Here's the code in the `EntryActivity`:

```
public class EntryActivity extends Activity {

// Tag
private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

// Inst.
private AccountManager accountManager;
private Account[] accounts;
private Authenticator authenticator;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    authenticator = new Authenticator(this);

    // Check for the account in account manager
    accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

    accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(HConstants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    int nAccounts = accounts.length;

    if(nAccounts!=0){
        // There's an account

    }
    else{
        // Prompt user to enter creds
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AuthenticationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

The problem is, I can't start the `AuthenticationActivity` and I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

How can I resolve this?

---

**Update:** Code for `AuthenticationActivity`:

```
public class AuthenticationActivity extends Activity {


// Instances
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

// Values for email and password at the time of the login attempt.
private String mEmail;
private String mPassword;

// UI references.
private EditText mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mLoginFormView;
private View mLoginStatusView;
private TextView mLoginStatusMessageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.authentication_activity);

    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mEmailView.setText(mEmail);

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mLoginStatusView = findViewById(R.id.login_status);
    mLoginStatusMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status_message);

}
```

Comment: where is your `setContentView`?

Comment: @Raghunandan, I don't have one. It's basically an invisible activity to start others.

Comment: does AuthenticationActivity extends Activity?

Comment: @Mahm00d post full code

Comment: if you dont have UI then why should you use activity?

Comment: @R9j all the same it is not the reason of that exception

Comment: @blackbelt, positive.

Comment: @Mahm00d did you tried transferring your code to onResume() ?

Comment: @R9j, did that. Still getting the error.

Comment: post the code @Raghunandan asked you

Comment: If you do not mind, could you post AuthenticationActivity ?

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: @blackbelt, thanks to making me look inside the `AuthenticationActivity`. It was a really stupid mistake [facepalm]. I was using the context (`this`) before the `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
```

I was using the context (system service) before `onCreate()`. By putting it inside the method, the error was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Put your check into `onStart()` instead of `onCreate()`. After starting the other activity, call `finish()` to stop your dummy activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onResume()` method. If this does not work directly try the following code (I don't fully recommend this):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      //Start your activity..
   }
}
```

This code inside your onResume

Comment: why should be it make difference?

Comment: Because those IllegalStateExceptions are really weird, i've read Android sources (Activity class, Fragment class) and Google check for some "State" flags to throw that exception, postDelayed will let the Activity finish its cycle, and then it will be able to call another activity

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in this line:

```
private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Try to move it into the `onCreate` method after the `super`. Hope this helps.

Comment: please, delete this question